# No sound from headphone jack Ubuntu 20.04 with NUC107i

Tags: sound, 20.04, headphones, intel-nuc

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a NUC107i. The system does not appear to recognize the 3.5 mm headphone jack with mic. When I plug in a HDMI monitor with speakers, the audio comes through the monitor fine, but I'm not able to get any sound from the headphones. The Sound Setting do not give the 3.5mm jack as an option. When I plug in a monitor with no speaker, I get the "Dummy Output" as the only option. How do i get the system to recognize the 3.5 mm jack? [Sound Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD18M.png)

Comment: paste 'aplay -l'   result: if you see other devices that HDMI, you have hope . Anyyway, remove fastboot in Windows if fastboot, and try disable/reenable audio in Bios/uefi

Comment: I have tried everything but don't see the 3.5 jack anywhere in the configuration. Finally plugged in a USB-headphone and managed to enable it with pavucontrol.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04 while it worked for Ubuntu 18.04. From similar problems with older versions I got this, which helped:

1. `sudo apt install pavucontrol`
2. start it with `pavucontrol`
3. plug in your headphones
4. Go to "Configuration" tab on the top right
5. Choose an analog profile

This magically switched the sounds to my headphones and showed them along with the microphone also in the standard sound settings dialog. It is also permanent: If I unplug my headphones, sound switches to HDMI and if I plug them in again, sound switches to headphones again. Now my headset is finally working under Ubuntu 20.04 on my NUC 6i.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way from the [Intel community forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-NUCs/NUC10i5-headphones-jack-audio-not-working-with-Ubuntu-20-04/m-p/1230587/highlight/true#M78398).

1. Open Terminal
2. Open the `alsa-base.conf` file with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
   ```
3. Add the following line to the end of the file:

   ```
   options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
   ```

4.Reboot

Now, when you plug in your headphones, a “Select Audio Device” dialog will appear:

[image: "select audio device"]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nico...problem solved exactly as you indicated.

Also migrated from 18.04 LTS to 19.0 to 20.04 LTS and had the same problem just recently.  Initially no problem with 20.04 LTS.  My laptop:Lenovo-ideapad 320.

Enjoying my earphones again !!

Comment: Update:  I unplugged my (new) earphones, then tried using it again after a while ... did not work again !!  Earphones not detected as Output Device under Sound settings.

Then read in another Ask Ubuntu post that earphones/headphones supposed to be detected automatically upon plugging in; which prompted me to wiggle and twist the plug of my new earphones in the jack on the side of laptop.  After several attempts, it was detected in Output Device, and now works well.  

So, cause of this simple problem: new earphone plug had bad initial fit in the jack !!  Hahaha....