# Ubuntu 20.04 headphones no sound, other sound devices work

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and my aux headphones don't work. In sound settings the sound bar is moving as some music is playing, but no sound actually comes out. I have tried installing PulseAudio, but that hasn't helped.

The output is called "Headphones - Starship/Mattise HD audio controller". Other outputs work, those would be my 3 monitors, so "HDMI/Displayport 1/2/3 - HDA Nvidia" and my speakers that are connected via front jack line out. That one is called "Line out Starship/Mattise HD audio controller"

https://askubuntu.com/a/1256373/1364232

I have tried this, but mine is already on "Analog stereo duplex" and any other of them didn't work, with "Analog Stereo Input" changing sound to play on my displayport 1 monitor.

Please let me know if I need to include any extra info, I am new. Thank you